# Chome: Only 6 videos are allowed to load / queue

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, html5-video, video.js, couch-cms

Having strange issues with chrome. I have a site that uses video.js, and displays multiple product videos. On IE and Firefox, all videos load fine - no problem. Chrome only seems to allow 6 to play. Now, im not trying to play 6 at one time, but i would like the thumbnails to at least populate. Content, interestingly, does not load either when you click play on videos that are not a part of the initial 6 that were loaded. In video.js, i have autoplay and other related tags that would kick off a video to play / queue disabled. Any way I can get around this limitation?

Thanks for any help! (Screenshot attached)
Additionally, i have test benched the site on codio:
http://jargon-cool.codio.io:3000/[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Here's what i did. You'll need to use `preload="metadata"` on your videos to pull the thumbnails but NOT queue the video (Therefore taking up a socket) Chrome has a max of 6 sockets, so this stops any more media streams (HTML audio / video) from running.